# Use of chain rule

Tags: chain-rule

How do I use the chain rule to determine the following?

$$\frac{d}{dx}sin(x+c)$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}sin(x+c)$$

Comment: Any thoughts?  What difference do you see between these two expressions?

Comment: I see that one is a normal derivative, whereas the other is a partial derivative. But I don't know how to apply the chain rule to solve them. Is there a particular rule (version of the chain rule) I should need to solve this?

Comment: As this is a function of one variable, what's the difference between an ordinary derivative and a partial?  What version of the chain rule do you know?  It's hard to imagine a more basic example of the chain rule than this.

Comment: In both cases, the result will be the same because $c$ is always considered as a constant.

Comment: May be worth remarking that the chain rule is not even needed here.  You can expand $\sin(x+c)$ using the additional formula for $\sin$ and then differentiate directly.  Otherwise, the standard chain rule works perfectly:  $\frac d{dx} f(g(x))=f'(g(x))\times g'(x)$.

Comment: Oh, well I've just realised that the results are the same since it is a function of only one variable (I was supposed to make an example where this wasn't the case, but forgot to add a second variable at least). There are 2 versions of the chain rule I know of. The first states "If $y=[f(x)]^n$, then $\frac{dy}{dx}=n[f(x)]^{n-1}f'(x)$ ". The other, I've only seen applications of, but I don't know the actual rule. An example of it being applied is "$\frac{\partial f(x+ct)}{\partial(x+ct)}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial(x+ct)}\frac{\partial(x+ct)}{\partial t}=f' \cdot c$"

Comment: Well, look up [the Chain Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).  Definitely worth learning the general rule, as opposed to a few special cases of it.

Comment: What are the other variables involved in your second expression